# Express the polynomial $ax^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+by^2+c$ in matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I'm given

$$\begin{bmatrix}x & y & 1\end{bmatrix}*M*\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

where $M$ is the polynomial $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c$ in matrix notation.

Im totally stumped here. I know how to compute a matrix product into a polynomial, i've tried dividing by the given matrices or breaking the terms of the polynomials by their products and reversing the steps from there, but I just don't see it as the right approach. Can anyone give me some guidance as to how to start this off. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the matrix $M=(a_{ij})$ then you can see that

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot M\cdot\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

you see by the definition of matrix multiplication you get

$$a_{11}x^2+a_{22}y^2+(a_{12}+a_{21})xy+(a_{13}+a_{31})x+(a_{23}+a_{32})y+a_{33}$$

so if you assume $M$ is symmetric (this is what is always done for quadratic forms represented by matrices) this is just

$$a_{11}x^2+a_{22}y^2+2a_{12}xy+2a_{13}x+2a_{23}y+a_{33}.$$

Comment: Ohh.. wow.. that's it haha. Thanks for this good answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$(x, y, 1)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & h & g \\
h & b & f \\
g & f & c \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
x  \\ y \\ 1 \end{array} \right)$$